# Ubuntu 16.04 detects 16GB SD cards but not 32GB cards on Lenovo Yoga Thinkpad

Tags: 16.04, lenovo, thinkpad, sd-card

I have just installed Ubuntu 16.04 on my Yoga Thinkpad and need to transfer some files from a 32GB SD card.

As the title mentions, Ubuntu does not detect the card. I thought the slot might not be connected properly (It is a used computer that I just bought), but I can see the slot with lspci and the card work fine on Xubuntu and Windows.

So I tried inserting other cards into the slot (all the other cards I have are 16GB) and they all work.

Any ideas? I've tried looking, but couldn't find anyone with the same problem.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a known problem with Card Compatibility on the Yoga.

A lot of users are experiencing the same issues you are.  It's not related directly to Ubuntu, but the machine itself.

There is a post on the Lenovo forums where users have been contributing their experiences with different brands and models of SD cards.

You can find it [here](https://forums.lenovo.com/t5/Android-Yoga-Series-Tablets/A-list-of-working-non-working-microSD-cards/td-p/2166052).

It contains a more comprehensive list of known working and non working cards.

It might pay to check your card against their list to see if it is affected.

Comment: You're welcome.  I hope they come up with a fix for you :)